# Scapy ARP not found error, finding Mac Address of Amazon Dash button

Tags: python, windows, scapy

So I'm attempting to follow [this guide](https://medium.com/@edwardbenson/how-i-hacked-amazon-s-5-wifi-button-to-track-baby-data-794214b0bdd8) to find the mac address of an Amazon dash button. I'm on a Windows machine running Python 2.6 and scapy. I'm fairly certain that I followed [these directions](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html) correctly on how to install Scapy on Windows so I don't think that's the issue.

My question is, everytime I run the code in Step 2 of the first link to sniff for the ARP Probe, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\ ... \scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 523, in sniff.
        r = prn(p)
    File "<console>", line 3, in arp_display
    File"C:\ ... \scapy\packet.py", line 789, in ___getitem___

raise IndexError("Layer [%s] not found" % lname)
IndexError: Layer [ARP] not found.
```

I'm not very familiar with scapy but it looks like it's not properly figuring out if the packet has an ARP layer? Also when starting scapy I get an error message about not being able to find a route for IPV6 destination (which apparently is normal?) and a few warnings that I haven't installed optional scapy features like Crypto Lib, gnuplot wrapper or PvX. Although I don't think those should really make a difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the same happen if you try with scapy 3.x?